# Drag and drop doesn't work when application running as administrator

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have a standard c# winforms exe with drag and drop enabled which is working fine, But when I run exe as Admin then drag and drop doesn't work. How I can sort this?

Answer (score 2):

[Answer from duplicated thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8239395/2310637)

> Lower-privileged processes cannot drag-and-drop to higher-privileged ones on Vista and later.

You can also open a file explorer *(for instance [TotalCommander](http://www.ghisler.com/))* as administrator, this will allow you to drag and drag, because they both run on the same privilege level.