# Debug Drag-And-Drop when running VS as Administrator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, drag-and-drop, elevated-privileges

I am adding drag-and-drop to a one-click application in Windows 8. I have to run Visual Studio 2010 as Administrator to import the signing key. Unfortunately, you cannot drag-and-drop from File Explorer to a VS application when running as Administrator.

I looked at a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239271/uac-elevation-does-not-allow-drag-and-drop), but it is for Windows 7; the solution does not work in Windows 8. I also looked at a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226600/visual-studio-does-not-let-me-drag-drop-items-into-it) to get File Explorer to run with Admin privileges, but that also did not work.

Currently I am reduced to building and then running from the exe, which means I cannot trace through the code at breakpoints. Is there a way to get around the UAC restrictions in Windows 8?

Comment: try my hack to run Explorer as admin: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=144776

Comment: Did my hack work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the vs-command for vs2010 extension for you purpose, download it from here:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf

As quested from vscommand blog:

> Because it is hosted inside Visual Studio it also allows you to drag and drop files to solution explorer when running Visual Studio as Administrator.

Now you have to start vs2010 in administrator mode, this can be achieved:

> In Windows 8, you have to right-click devenv.exe and select
>   "Troubleshoot compatibility".
>
> 1. select "Troubleshoot program"
> 2. check "The program requires additional permissions"
> 3. click "Next",click "Test the program..."
> 4. wait for the program to launch
> 5. click "Next"
> 6. select "Yes, save these settings for this program"
> 7. click "Close"

Source: [Can you force Visual Studio to always run as an Administrator in Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257110/can-you-force-visual-studio-to-always-run-as-an-administrator-in-windows-8)

I hope it addresses your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already have VS set up to always run as admin. I did this through a shortcut. I installed VS-Command, but do not see how to launch File Explorer from it.

Comment: It is under Tools - VSCommands in main menu. You can also press Ctrl+Q in Visual Studio to go to Quick Launch and type word 'eleavated' there. The link below may assist you: http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/tgonzalez/archive/2013/12/09/working-with-azure-fixing-vs-solution-explorer-drag-amp-drop/